# PHP UNIX Timestamp int(10) DST

Tags: php, mysql, time, dst

Dates are my nemesis, I just can't figure them out so excuse the lame question! I support a LAMP based application. At 2am tomorrow, the clocks go back 1hr due to Daylight Savings. I am just trying to figure out if I need to make any adjustments to my app code and/or data. Here is the setup:

Server Time is UTC

PHP Timezone is set with date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Dublin');

The MySql Table CREATE statement is:

```
CREATE TABLE  `databasename`.`events` (
`id` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`name` VARCHAR( 40 ) NOT NULL ,
`event_date` INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

I store events using:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `events` (`name`, `event_date`) VALUES ('name', ".time().")");
```

I check for upcoming events in the database using a query similar to this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `events` WHERE `event_date` - " . time() . " < 0");
```

---

Will events after 2am tomorrow go out 1 hr early or should I be ok?

Comment: It could be the case for event at *exactly* 2AM.

Comment: Thanks - edit to add, the first query is incorrect. it should be : sql_query("INSERT INTO `events` (`name`, `event_date`) VALUES ('name', ".$epochinfuture.")");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Europe/Dublin' should use Dublin's DST (switch automatically), so you're good

Comment: Ok thanks for that - So just to get my head around it (and I'm sure others will search for this for years to come!), PHP's time() function takes into account timezone settings and is not just UTC as I had feared. eg: mktime(1:59am) == mktime(2:59am)?

Comment: date_default_timezone_set sets the TZ, all the time related functions use it then
there are physical time zones (they look like stripes on the map) and "real" time used by different cities/countries with dst and other things they often jump to other time zones  and back. That's why php uses city related settings and not the "utc +1" kind of syntax. Dublin was actually out of its physical time zone and will get back soon, thanks to this piece of code date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Dublin'); it's not your problem

Comment: All went well in regards events not going out too early but some new events added for between 1am and 2am were late.

php's mktime() cannot determine which hour instance you are talking about and it correctly defaults to the 2nd hour. Or in other words, there are 25 real hours in the day but mktime() only covers 24 of them. eg: At 1am (before switch), if you want an event to go out at 1.10am (10 mins in future) this will not do work: mktime(1,10,0,10,30,2011);

Comment: @Niall, if it's not a simple task better use [DateTime objects](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), they do the job, at least for me, even in "time related" projetcs :) Didn't have any dst-bugs on the Project that operates multiple timezones